# Got "Unexpected end of input" in Javascript when making a Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
        name: client.user.username,
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
      },
      title: "commands",
      description: "all current commands",
      fields: [{
        name: "admin only",
        value: "ban"
      },
      {
        name: "moderator only",
        value: "kick"
      },
      {
        name: "everyone",
        value: "ping \n help \n invite \n sinvite \n gay \n owner "
      }],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
        text: "~Isabelle~"
      }
    }
  });
  ^
SyntaxError; Unexpected end of input
```

I'm using discord.js within node.js, and I'm unsure what's causing this error. I've tried checking back for typos but I haven't caught any. Help?

Comment: You're missing a closing `});` for the `client.on` callback. Run your code through a linter like jslint, and even having consistent formatting like you can find on http://jsbeautifier.org/ can help you solve these syntax issues much faster

Comment: Yep, what Sterling said - I'd also recommend keeping your code formatted nicely (consistent spacings) so you can easily detect where brackets are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, add `});` to the very end of your code. This should close off the `client.on` event listener. The final `});` in your code looked like it closed off that listener until I edited the question with proper formatting. Now you can tell there is another `});` needed.

Credit goes to @SterlingArcher, I answered b/c I want to stop looking at this as an unanswered question.